# Moving a Sprite along a UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uibezierpath, skaction

I have been having some trouble moving a Sprite along a `UIBezierPath`. I am getting this path from my view controller and it is passing along the correct path. Any ideas on why this isn't animating? Eventually I want to be able to move multiple sprites along different bezier paths.

```
func play(){
    let img = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"ball.png")
    img.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/4, y: self.frame.size.height/4)
    self.addChild(img)

    new_path = viewController.path //UIBezierPath is being returned

    let followPath = SKAction.follow(new_path.cgPath, asOffset: true, orientToPath: false, duration: 5.0)

    img.run(followPath)
}
```

I am trying to draw a bezier path here(Kind of like a whiteboard app)in a custom view and then access the bezier path when I want to animate it. The path seems to be passed through correctly.

```
private var path: UIBezierPath!
let newpath = UIBezierPath()

func initBezierPath() {
    path = UIBezierPath()
    path.lineCapStyle = CGLineCap.round
    path.lineJoinStyle = CGLineJoin.round
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch: AnyObject? = touches.first
    lastPoint = touch!.location(in: self)
    pointCounter = 0
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch: AnyObject? = touches.first
    let newPoint = touch!.location(in: self)

    path.move(to: lastPoint)
    path.addLine(to: newPoint)
    lastPoint = newPoint

    pointCounter += 1

    if pointCounter == pointLimit {
        pointCounter = 0
        renderToImage()
        setNeedsDisplay()
        newpath.append(path)
        path.removeAllPoints()            
    }
    else {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }        
}
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    pointCounter = 0
    renderToImage()
    setNeedsDisplay()
    newpath.append(path)
    path.removeAllPoints()
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Please do not post your code as an image. Please [edit] your question by pasting the actual code into your question as text (and be sure it is formatted properly).

Comment: Sorry about that. Just updated my post!

Comment: Show us how you create new_path.

Comment: @ElTomato I just added it

Comment: You are obviously not setting an appropriate path to new_path.

Comment: @ElTomato I think I am in the touchesEnded method. Thank you for your help!

Comment: It would be appropriate if you read a book and learn basics.

Comment: did you still need help with this?

Comment: @Fluidity yes i do

Comment: so is the sprite supposed to move AS you draw the path?

Comment: also, there are a lot of funcs in here that you do not have listed... please post the funcs, or remove as much code as you can to help us isolate the problem

Comment: your other question is put on hold but I am still working on that answer as well. I've got the toolbar working, now I just need to implement the drag + drop... then you want the sprite to move along the path? As you draw?

Comment: Maybe you should ask 2 questions... 1 about how to do the toolbox, then another about how to do the drag + drop =]